# When does $\|\int{K_{j}(x,y)f(y)dy}\|\rightarrow 0$ implies $\lim_{j\rightarrow \infty}K_{j}(x,y)=0$ a.e.?

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose we have $\|\int{K_{j}(x,y)f(y)dy}\|_{L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)}\rightarrow 0$, as $j\rightarrow \infty$, holds for all $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$, then when can we obtain the pointwise estimates $\lim_{j\rightarrow \infty}K_{j}(x,y)=0$ a.e.?

For example, if we assume further that we have $\lim_{j\rightarrow \infty} \int{K_{j}(x,y)f(x)g(y)dxdy}=0$, for all $f,g\in C_{0}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, then is the above result hold?

Answer (score 0):

Take $K_j(x,y):=x\sin(jy)\chi_{(0,1)}(y)\chi_{(0,1)}(x)$: using an approximation argument and Riemann-Lebesgue lemma, we get that $\lVert \int K_j(x,y)f(y)\mathrm dy\to 0$ for each $f\in\mathbb L^1(\mathbb R^n)$.

But we don't have the almost everywhere convergence.